# Your day is my hour

Tags: riddle

> Your day is my hour,
>
> Your week is my day,
>
> Your month is my 2 days.

**What am I?**

Comment: I would guess ... stoned? ;)

Comment: Can I change my guess to "The Doctor"?

Comment: @KeyurPATEL How about "The Stoned Doctor"?

Answer (score 2):

Another potential answer:

You are

> a Minute Hand

and *I* am

> an Hour Hand

Your day is my hour

> One rotation of the hour hand (me) comprises 12 hours.  if we take the definition of 'day' to mean 'daytime,' this is about one day's worth of time. 
>  One rotation a the minute hand (you) sweeps out 60 min, which is one hour

Your week is my day,

> An hour hand takes 14 rotations to carve out one week of time
>  14 rotations of the minute hand is 14 hours, about equal to 1 day under the previous definition.

Your month is my 2 days.

> An hour hand takes about 60 rotations to accrue one month of time
>  60 rotations of the minute hand is 60 hours, which is 2.5 days, or 2 *full* days

Note:

> iffy because I'm playing with the definition of a 'day,' but it otherwise holds up.

Answer (score 0):

My guess

> You are a player of a MMORPG (online game), with system
>  You are talking to the game : 
>  *Your(The game) day is my hour, your(The game) week is my day, your(The game) month is my 2 days*
>  
>  1 day in the game = 1 earth hour,  
>  1 week in the  game = 1 earth day, 
>  1 month in the  game = 2 earth days,
>  but I still do not know what kind of game it is.

Comment: But then what is 24 "my" hours equivalent to? 24 days or a week?

Comment: I think you've reversed it, he said 'Your day is my hour', and not 'Your hour is my day'.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL Your day (the game) is my hour (the player)

Comment: Ohhh, I misunderstood. So the player is talking to the system, with this poem. Makes sense :)

Comment: 24:1 becomes 7:1 becomes 30:2? That doesn't sound like a tenable game system

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a stretch, like a really far stretch

I think it could be

> Pluto

Your week is my day

> Based purely on the fact that one day on Pluto is just under a week on earth.

Your month is my 2 days

> It orbits really slowly?